# How do I programmatically restore an Apex 5 report to default state?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive report in Apex 5, and each time the page load, I want it to look exactly as it was shown the first time I ran it, with default settings.

The problem is that if the user applies any filter, or hide columns, the next time the page loads, the report remembers that configuration.

I tried to use the APEX_IR.RESET_REPORT procedure undocumented here:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_ir.htm#BABEJAFB

but it either doesn't works, or only undoes the last change, or needs many runs to actually work.

I tried a dynamic action at page load with this code:

```
DECLARE  
  v_region_id APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE;  
BEGIN  


  SELECT region_id INTO v_region_id  
  FROM APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS  
  WHERE application_id = :APP_ID  
  AND page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID  
  AND static_id = 'Images_Report'; 


   APEX_IR.RESET_REPORT(  
       P_page_id => :APP_PAGE_ID,  
       P_region_id => v_region_id,  
       p_report_id => null

  );  

END;
```

And I also tried this code

```
DECLARE  
  v_region_id APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE;  
BEGIN  


  SELECT region_id INTO v_region_id  
  FROM APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS  
  WHERE application_id = :APP_ID  
  AND page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID  
  AND static_id = 'Images_Report'; 


   APEX_IR.RESET_REPORT(  
       P_page_id => :APP_PAGE_ID,  
       P_region_id => v_region_id,  
       p_report_id => APEX_IR.GET_LAST_VIEWED_REPORT_ID(
                        p_page_id   => :APP_PAGE_ID,
                        p_region_id => v_region_id
                       )

  );  

END;
```

I expect the report to look as in default state (on first run), every time I load the page.

Instead the report shows the last state, even if the user logs out, logs in and restarts the application.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache when defining the target page?

Comment: @Blurryface I set the clear cache on the button which redirects to the interactive report, but it doens't works. (option Button>Properties>Behavior>Target>Clear Session State>Clear Cache)

Comment: That's wierd. Just like @scott mentioned you could either have URL with RIR as the clear cache in your URL or have RIR/CIR or the target page in your clear cache text field when you opt to have action as 'redirect to a page' instead. This should clear out all the filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send RIR as the clear cache parameter in your URL

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/linking-to-interactive-reports.htm#GUID-B917CEB3-A0B9-414B-A90A-7B44DD15EA67

URL would look like

```
f?p=102:94:6722612001859::NO:RIR::
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-url-syntax.htm#HTMDB03019

The documentation states this regarding the apex_ir.reset_report procedure

> This procedure should only be used in page submit processes.

Which could be why you had trouble